# ui-router : Error using <ui-view> inside a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Im using `0.3.1` version of `ui-router`.

My custom directive has `<ui-view></ui-view>` tag inside.

```
<div >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-lg pull-left" ui-sref="users.adduser"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

I get error below in console :

```
angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property '$$animLeave' of undefined
    at angular-ui-router.min.js:7
    at angular.js:16170
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17257)
    at angular.js:17483
    at e (angular.js:5955)
    at angular.js:6234
```

What's wrong with `ui-router`? Is this a `bug` in version `0.3.1`?

If not what im doing wrong!?

Comment: I don't think that GitHub link has anything to do with the problem you're having. Do you load your scripts dynamically with requireJS or something similar?

Comment: @CobusKruger yes it was irrelevant and i edit my question, my mistake. No im not using requireJs but using gulp to concat all js files into one. my app is working with this error in console.

Comment: I use Grunt in a similar way and there's no reason it shouldn't work. Have you checked the order in which the files are concatenated? Should be jQuery, then Angular, then UI router, then any directives, services and controllers and only then your module that bootstraps Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The ui-router github repo reported it as a bug (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3004). In my case I am using the 0.3.1 version and my code looked something like this.

```
<body>
  <div ui-view></div>

     <div ui-view>  //sub ui-view
         //content
     </div>      
</body>
```

And I got rid of this error by removing first `ui-view` from div and putting `<ui-view></ui-view>`

```
<body>
      <ui-view></ui-view>

         <div ui-view>  //sub ui-view 
             //content
         </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```